# Script not working when run in terminal

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-line

I have this simple command saved as `.sh`-file

```
xdg-open https://stackoverflow.com
```

upon opening it, I can choose between launching it directly or in a terminal. However, it only works when opening it directly. When I chose "Run in Terminal", it shows a Terminal, which instantly closes again and nothing happens.

Why does this behave differently and how do fix it, since I later need user input in the script from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the 'shebang' to the first line of your script.:

```
#!/bin/bash
xdg-open https://stackoverflow.com
```

This tells how the script is executed or which interpreter should be run to execute your code.

Then you need the execute permission for it. You can set it in the properties in your GUI or commandline

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
```

After this you should be able to execute it and your default browser should open a new window.

Comment: unfortunately I tried both of these already, and it still doesn't work...